# Testing if a password for an eCryptfs mount is valid

Tags: file-encryption, password-based-encryption, disk-encryption

I'm using *"eCryptfs"* on several directories on my dedicated Debian server. I mount them manually via

```
mount -t ecryptfs [dir] [mountpoint]
```

But after some weeks being mounted it's not easy to remember the exact passwords for each directory. I want to make sure that I got the right passwords before unmounting them or rebooting the server.

I thought of generating an *"eCryptfs"* signature and comparing it with the directory's *"eCryptfs"* signature. Which parameters do I need to know and what is the algorithm for the *"eCryptfs"* signature? And is this the right way to verify my password?

Comment: This appears to be a tech support question about using or fixing technology to work as advertised. [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) could provide more in-deep and more on-point answers on how to use the related software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ecryptfs-add-passphrase](http://manpg.es/ecryptfs-add-passphrase) command to add a passphrase to your kernel keyring, which will also print the signatures (hashes) to standard out.

Once you've added a passphrase to the keyring, you might want to clear it, using the [keyctl](http://manpg.es/keyctl) command.

[eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org) uses a [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)-like, [key strengthening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) algorithm of 65536 rounds of [SHA512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

<sub>(**Disclosure:** I am one of the authors and maintainers of [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org).)</sub>

Comment: When you specify that it is using said algorithm, it would appear that is an algorithm used to generate a key from the passphrase, said key being used for a symetric cipher. If that is the case, how is the signature generated?